# CodeIgniter Message: Class 'Model' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello guys i am trying to connect my database to get some data using codeigniter , there is my code:

i am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Model' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ci/application/models/Data_model.php on line 3
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ci/application/models/Data_model.php:3)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 569
>
> Backtrace:
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Class 'Model' not found
>   Filename: models/Data_model.php
>
> Line Number: 3
>   Backtrace:

Models:
Data_model.php:

```
<?php 

class Data_model extends Model {


    function getAll(){

        $q  = $this->db->query("SELECT * from data");

        if($q->num_rows() > 0) {

            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data [] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }

    }
}
```

views:
home.php

```
<htmL>

<body>


<div> view has been loaded</div>


<!--<p>  <?php echo $myValue; ?> </p>

<p>  <?php echo $anotherValue; ?> </p> -->



<pre>

<?php foreach ($rows as $r) {
    echo '<h1>' . $r->title . '</h1>';
}
?>
</pre>

</body>


</htmL>
```

controllers:
site.php

```
<?php 

Class Site extends CI_Controller {


  function __construct()
  {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
  }

  function index(){

    $this->load->model('data_model');
    $data['rows'] = $this->data_model->getAll();

    $this->load->view('home', $data);

  }
}
```

Comment: try class Data_model extends CI_Model. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always make sure that you extends your model with CI_Model for it will be recognized .

```
 class Model extends CI_Model {

 //you can always put function construct

    public function __construct (){
      parent::__construct ();

   }
}
```

In your controller :

```
class Sample extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct () {
     parent:: __construct();
     //you can load here the model that you will just often so will load it everytime to use it in a function

   $this->load->model('nameofModel');

  }
}
```

Remember : The name of the model or controller must be the same with its filename.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your class extends the base Model class. In CodeIgniter this is "CI_Model"...

```
class Data_model extends CI_Model {
    // Your model class code here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have already load Model
for that:
1.open application/config/autoload.php
and 
2. edit 
`$autoload['model'] = array('');` with

```
$autoload['model'] = array('Model');
```

thats works